# Javascript image height and other calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was having a problem on getting the height and also calculating other calculations.

I want to get the image height after it has loaded, so I put it on the onload attribute of `<img></img>` function, here's my code

```
<p class="test1" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;">
   <img src="'+getBaseURL()+'js/check/no-image.png" rel="fullname"
        onload="verticalCenter()"/>
</p>

function verticalCenter(){
    var imageHeight = jQuery(".test1 img").height(); //I get a result of 0
    var total = imageHeight / 2 + 80
}
```

I already tried using setTimeout but it still fails.
What I was planning to do here is to set the css  of `<p class="test1">` into like this:

```
jQuery(".test1").css("bottom","-"+total);
```

As I said, this isn't working because I don't get a result in total.

How would I do this, Is there a way to solve this problems, I'm already scratching my head on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this in the onload event? Seems like its trying to get a height when the image hasn't loaded yet. So instead of .ready try `$(window).load(function () {\\code here}`

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Rather than revise my answer, I've deleted it.  You should answer this one ;-)

Comment: Take a serious look at @Matt's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function () {

    var imageHeight = jQuery(".test1 img").height(); //I get a result of 0
    var total = imageHeight / 2 + 80

}


<p class="test1" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;">
   <img src="'+getBaseURL()+'js/check/no-image.png" rel="fullname"/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need units on CSS dimensions.

```
jQuery(".test1").css("bottom","-"+total+"px");
```

You should also check to make sure that `total` is the value you are expecting it to be before setting it.

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yHqr7/

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to set all the image heights when the form is ready:

```
$(document).ready(
    $('p.text1 img').each(verticalCenter);
)
```

Unless you're using ajax to load the images; if that is the case, then you should use the live() event:

```
$('p.text1 img').live(verticalCenter);
```

Then in your function you can set everything:

```
function verticalCenter(){
    $(this).css('bottom',"-" + ($(this).height() / 2 + 80) + 'px');
}
```

Comment: By the way, I made a mistake here, It should be like this: